# Collaborative documentation management software

Tags: web-apps, document-management, git

I'm looking for an `open-source` software for collaborative documentation management with the following:

1. May be installed on local server
2. May be connected to Active Directory for authentification
3. Versions control
4. Compare of versions and track changes

I use **Gitlab**, however, unfortunately, it doesn't accept MS office (doc,docx) for versions control and comparing in the Web appication.

Comment: Comparing MS Office files is the hardest point, especially within a web application.

Comment: A long shot, but via document conversion that might help, I'll wait for answers over there: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/118777/output-document-version-differences-in-headless-mode/

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider **Google Docs** and if you did, what aspect of Google Docs fails to deliver your requirements?

Collaboration is superb, history tracking/version control is also supported out of the box and it allows you to download the document in various document formats in case you need that too (PFDs, open documents, MS office formats...)